Nonparametric test for means?
Is there a nonparametric test for equality of means using two independent samples?
The most popular nonparametric tests compare medians instead. That makes sense because they are more robust to outliers which in textbooks are a motivation for nonparametrics in the first case.
But in the real world, another motivation for nonparametrics is to defend oneself against misinformed reviewers of applied journals who believe that normality of the data-generating process is necessary to conduct a z-test.
If the underlying research question concerns the mean and not the median, is there a specialized nonparametric procedure that can be deployed? (Of course, one could bootstrap etc, but just curious).

Permutations tests?

@MichaelLew maybe I should have been more explicit, but this is what I was imagining as part of the "etc" for "bootstrap etc" :)

The most popular non-parametric tests don't actually use medians -- the test for medians (Mood's test) isn't that widely used.  You probably mean the Wilcoxon tests, which don't use medians.
If you want a test of the null hypothesis of equal means, you can use a permutation test and probably make reviewers happy. This isn't quite correct: the test is only distribution-free under the strong null hypothesis of equal distributions, not under the hypothesis of equal means. However, it's better than the Wilcoxon test as a test of means because the power goes to 100% as the means get more different and the test can't reject in the opposite direction to the difference in means, and the Type I error when the means are the same but the distributions are different isn't too far from the nominal. And the reviewers probably believe it is exact, even when it isn't

Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I've never heard of Mood's test. The Wilcoxon and Mann-Whitney tests don't use sample medians, but they do test for equality of population medians under certain regularity conditions, which is what I was referring to. You're right that we can use general-purpose tools like permutation tests. I suppose though that you're not aware of a specific procedure along the lines of Wilcoxon/ Mood's/Mann-Whitney, specifically designed for testing mean equality without distributional assumptions?

The assumption of a permutation test when translated into the realm of populations may require equal distribution, but the actual assumption of random assignment will deal with that naturally. No population is needed. Random allocation is not the same as random sampling and so it is only in some circumstances that the use of a permutations test will bring a need to consider distributions.

For example, if the variances of two groups are different but the means are equal, the permutation test will not have its nominal level.

@JohnMadden The null hypothesis of Wilcoxon/MW is that the distributions are the same, in which case of course also the medians are the same, as are the means (as long as they exist). Otherwise there isn't any specific situation I'm aware of in which Wilcoxon/MW is particularly related to medians.  (You can easily construct situations in which WMW will reject despite medians being equal, and in which WMW will not normally reject yet medians are different.)

@JohnMadden The Wikipedia page for WMW says that "Under more strict assumptions than the general formulation above, e.g., if the responses are assumed to be continuous and the alternative is restricted to a shift in location, we can interpret a significant Mann–Whitney U test as showing a difference in medians." But then this would also imply a difference in means. If you refer to anything else as basis for WMW being about medians "under certain regularity conditions", please let me know. I'm eager to learn. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test

Perhaps this could be a useful read: Should the Median Test be Retired from General Use?. The test has been mentioned in Mood, Graybill's undergrad statistics textbook.

Hey @ChristianHennig thanks for your reply; no that's what I was referring to.


The most popular nonparametric tests compare medians instead.

They don't. The most popular two-sample nonparametric tests would be the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test for the independent-samples case and the Wilcoxon signed rank test for the paired case. Neither compares medians (unless you add further assumptions, and if you add such assumptions you could just as easily claim they're a test for means, as long as population means are finite).

Is there a nonparametric test for equality of means using two independent samples?

Sure; there's permutation and bootstrap tests, for example.
If you are prepared to assume that - when $H_0$ is true - the shapes and spreads will be the same or about the same, then I'd recommend a permutation test. In some situations this is easily justifiable, in others, perhaps less so. I'd typically suggest using a t-statistic for the test statistic - this will still measure the number of standard errors of the difference in mean that the means are apart and so in that sense is still interpretable.  It will also give you a more direct comparison with a p-value from an ordinary t-test, since you are comparing two p-value calculations based on the same statistic.
However, when the population variances are equal or the sample sizes are quite similar, a direct comparison of means will still be asymptotically robust.
Indeed, Chung and Romano [1] suggest studentizing permutation statistics because they are more robust against violations of exchangeability. More specifically in the case of the comparison of two sample means they specifically suggest replacing the difference in means with a statistic equivalent to a Welch-type t statistic. It will still work when  exchangeability holds  but it will behave better when the ordinary difference in means or the ordinary t-test will not perform as you might hope.
If you don't want to assume that the shapes and spreads will be similar under $H_0$, then another approach would be a suitable bootstrap test (perhaps one based on a Welch t-statistic, again; pivotal or nearly pivotal quantities are generally a good idea for bootstrap tests). It's quite suitable in large samples but getting good level control may be somewhat more difficult in small samples; there are strategies which may improve this, but I don't wish to launch into an extended discussion of dealing with such issues here.
On the whole both should do quite well but if samples are not large I tend to lean toward the permutation test using the Welch statistic (unless sample sizes are equal where I don't tend to worry but there's little to lose even there); it's easy to implement, relatively easy to understand what the statistic says and has good level-robustness in a wide variety of situations.
On the other hand if you have a more suitable distributional model, relative power may be an important consideration. In such a case you can look to a statistic that will have good power when that model is correct but use a nonparametric test - say a permutation test - based on that statistic. For example, if you were dealing with say interevent duration times, a ratio of means might be a more suitable statistic than a difference. If, for example, the durations were exponential, then the test should have good power when the model was correct, while keeping the level as desired if the exponential model wasn't correct (under exchangeability).
Such an approach can potentially be applied even with a likelihood ratio statistic, at least in some situations.
However, again, Chung and Romano's points about robustness in the absence of exchangeability will still apply so where possible you may still want to engage in suitable scaling as an additional safeguard, even when you think the model is likely to be suitable.

[1] EunYi Chung, Joseph P. Romano (2013), "Exact and asymptotically robust permutation tests", The Annals of Statistics, 41(2) 484-507
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-41/issue-2/Exact-and-asymptotically-robust-permutation-tests/10.1214/13-AOS1090.full
alternate location: https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5939
